# Grow and shrink the image when page is opened

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have written a code and I'm trying to shrink/grow images when page is opened. I want to  do this automatically(maybe simple jQuery animation).

But I can make it work on mouse hover. I want it when page is opened.

My code: http://jsfiddle.net/THfCe/

Code:

```
<style>
    #photos img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        transition: width 2s, height 2s, transform 2s;
        margin-left: -10px;
    }
    #photos img:hover {
        width: 110%;
        height:110%;
    }
</style>
<div id="photos">
    <img src="http://www.oprant.com/images/p_slide1.png" alt="Main" id="mainpicture" class="resize" />
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking for?

Comment: @ekstrakt How can i resize image when page open <<--

Comment: I still don't understand what quite are you asking for, but set the initial width and height of the img to 110%.

`#photos img{
    width:110%;
    height:110%;
    ...
}

Comment: @ekstrakt Look up, its my code and working when mouseover image resizing %110, i want to WHEN PAGE OPEN resize %110

Comment: @Ryliatron Do you mean to have an animation kind of effect wherein the image gets bigger and then to its original size when page is opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo that I have created. See if this is the functionality what you are trying-

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/EsvHM/4/) (*Updated*)

jQuery-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  repeat();
});

function repeat()
{
$("#myImg").animate({
        left: '50px',
        height: '45px',
        width: '50px'
    }, "slow");
    $("#myImg").animate({
        left: '0px',
        width:'34px',
        height: '37px',
    }, "slow",repeat);
}
```

**Update**: Give an Id to your image tag so that the animation is applied only to a particular image.

Comment: its awesome, thank you so much **but** why its stopping.. how can we do never stop version?

Comment: Updated the answer. Simple put the animation in a function and call it at the end so that it goes in an infinite loop.

Comment: Updated once again. Now you shouldn't have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the image to be as large as the browser viewport is. If that's the case, your code is almost there. You just need to set the image's container to also have 100% width/height.

```
html, body, #photos { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

An element with 100% width/height can only be as large as it's container. In your case, the html, body, and photos elements. If you have any additional containers, you'll need to add it to the CSS code above.

Comment: thank you for answer but you dont understand me (if i understand your answer) Look up, its my code and working when mouseover image resizing %110, i want to WHEN PAGE OPEN resize %110. and again thank you.